# Maintaining a Caching Appliance

Tags: caching, maintenance-plan

What are typical cache appliance maintenance tasks and schedule for same?

Answer (score 0):

With a caching appliance it has mostly the similar tasks as other servers have. You have to make sure that only the intended users are using it, the hardware is working, its on, it has netaccess, etc.

The only differences in it are that you need to make sure that the content that it is caching is relivant and stays fresh. You also may want to check the file system everyonce and a while, etc.